# Angular ng-if triggered always that Ui Router $state.is is different to something

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to write an ng-if expression with Ui Router in Angular, so that it would be triggered always that the state doesn't match one state in particular.

Something like `$state.is(!'notThisState')`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
<div ng-if="$state.current.name !== 'notThisState'">
 Your div goes here.
</div>
```